# calling virtual enviroment python from matlab

Tags: python, matlab, virtualenv

I recently created a script in matlab and have needed to call a script in python:

```
system([virtualenv/bin/python my_python_script])
```

However, I receive this error:

**undefined symbol: XML_SetHashSalt**

My Matlab version is R2018a, my operative system is Linux server 4.15.0-43-generic and   version python virtual environment is 3.5.2